# sort keeping 2 items on top

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an array object like

```
const d = [
    { id: 20, text: 'deaf' },
    { id: 30, text: 'acta', },
    { id: 0, text: 'deema1' },
    { id: -1, text: 'deema2' },
]
```

I want to sort the array by text but want to keep id -1 and 0 always on top, so the result would be

```
// sorted
[
    { id: -1, text: 'deema2' },
    { id: 0, text: 'deema1' },
    { id: 30, text: 'acta' },
    { id: 20, text: 'deaf' },
]
```

I tried to sort like `d.sort((a, b) => (a.text).localeCompare(b.text))` but not sure how to handle case -1 and 0

```js
const d = [
    { id: 20, text: 'deaf' },
    { id: 30, text: 'acta', },
    { id: 0, text: 'deema1' },
    { id: -1, text: 'deema2' },
];

d.sort((a, b) => (a.text).localeCompare(b.text))

console.log(d);
```

Comment: You could write your own function compare instead of using `localeCompare` and hardcode the results if ids are `0` or `-1` in it.

Comment: Remove your special cases, sort regularly, place your special cases on the desired spot?

Comment: In your example, `deema2` appears twice in the desired output. Is there any required order among the objects that have those special  `id` values?

Comment: @trincot: I assume that `{ id: 0, text: 'deema2' }` is a typo, which should be `{ id: 0, text: 'deema1' }`.  And the expected result, given that all modern JS sorts are stable, make me assume that those are expected to be ordered `-1` before `0`, whether that's an arbitrary list like in your first solution or is numeric is still unclear.

Comment: @trincot that was a typo, I fixed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work with `indexOf`:

```js
const d = [
    { id: 20, text: 'deaf' },
    { id: 30, text: 'acta', },
    { id: 0, text: 'deema1' },
    { id: -1, text: 'deema2' },
    { id: 0, text: 'ace' },
    { id: -999, text: 'hello' },
    { id: 800, text: 'game' },
]

d.sort((a, b) => [0,-1].indexOf(b.id) - [0,-1].indexOf(a.id) 
                 || a.text.localeCompare(b.text));

console.log(d);
```

This will order all objects with `id` -1 first, and among those, the `text` property will define the order, then all objects with `id` 0, (again relatively ordered by `text`) and finally all other objects by `text`.

In case you want there to be no distinction between 0 and -1, but sort all those by `text` among themselves, then use `includes` instead of `indexOf`:

```js
const d = [
    { id: 20, text: 'deaf' },
    { id: 30, text: 'acta', },
    { id: 0, text: 'deema1' },
    { id: -1, text: 'deema2' },
    { id: 0, text: 'ace' },
    { id: -999, text: 'hello' },
    { id: 800, text: 'game' },
]

d.sort((a, b) => [0,-1].includes(b.id) - [0,-1].includes(a.id) 
                 || a.text.localeCompare(b.text));

console.log(d);
```

Comment: A useful feature of this answer is that it also makes it immediately clear how to make this more generic, using a supplied list of ids to keep at the top.  I'm not so thrilled with using the magical casting of the boolean result of `includes` to an integer for a subtraction; I'd prefer to be more explicit.  (But I am not your downvoter and would certainly not downvote for that!)

Comment: I guess I'm a little inconsistent on that, as I have no problem with the casting of an integer to a boolean for the `||`.  Damn, I hate finding my own inconsistencies! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can put multiple conditions inside of `sort` to get the desired result. The first condition being more important than the next and so on.
This is how it would look like:

```js
const d = [{
    id: 20,
    text: 'deaf'
  },
  {
    id: 30,
    text: 'acta',
  },
  {
    id: 0,
    text: 'deema1'
  },
  {
    id: -1,
    text: 'deema2'
  },
]

const sorted = d.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.id === -1) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.id === 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  return a.text.localeCompare(b.text);
});

console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: I would not downvote because of it, but there is a possible gap, with all values that have `id` of `-1` sorting in source order (and similarly for `0`.)  I think trincot's choice to further sort by `text` makes more sense.  But that would be the OP's call.

Comment: Its outputting wrong order, the final order should be deema1/-1, deema2/0, acta/30, deaf/20. In short order should be id having -1 then id having 0 then sorted by text asc.

Comment: @coure2011 I think you misread something. The element with `id: -1` has the `text` value `deema2` in my example array. We're not changing `text` values between elements here, we're just sorting array values (the objects as a whole) between themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modified from one of the answer above to use the pipe operator, this way you can add any other numbers you wish just by using more pipes.

```
const d = [
    { id: 20, text: 'deaf' },
    { id: 30, text: 'acta', },
    { id: 0, text: 'deema1' },
    { id: -1, text: 'deema2' },
    { id: 0, text: 'ace' },
    { id: -999, text: 'hello' },
    { id: 800, text: 'game' },
]

const sorted = d.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.id === -1 || a.id === 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  return a.text.localeCompare(b.text);
});

console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: Sure, but trincot's answer does the same thing, with less repetition, by simply putting the top ids into an array.